# Como dividir o painel de administração do módulo em duas seções?

Tags: magento

Eu criei um novo módulo de pagamento. O novo método de pagamento tem duas opções e gostaria de separa-los em seções diferentes, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como dividir o painel de administração do módulo em duas seções?

Estou utilizando a versão 1.9.2.2.

Comment: Dá pra vc usar usar um colapso não?

Comment: @Marconi como seria utilizando colapso?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse dá uma olhadinha aqui, dá pra implementar de acordo com  o que vc quer.